# Cypress: Enter value into siblings

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to enter value into input box below the Quantity field.
[image]

I tried below code , but didnt work

```
cy.contains('Quantity').siblings('input').type(123)
```

and

```
cy.contains('Quantity').siblings('div').type(123)
```

[image]

Comment: what about ```cy.contains('Quantity').closest('div').find('input').type('123') ``` ?

Comment: @RajeshPaudel thanks for the hint, but this didnt work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to use a combination of `parent()` and `within`.

```js
cy.contains('Quantity')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('[inputmode="numeric"]').clear().type('123')
    cy.get('.cc-1mkztvr').clear().type('123') //In case above doesn't work, find element with class name
  })
```